# ProFTPD: Disable writing and deleting to a particular directory

Tags: ftp, write, proftpd

How would I prevent writing and deleting to the `~/site/backups/` directory in the ProFTPD config?

So far: I think I have figured out how to disable any kind of deleting:

```
  <Directory ~/site/backups>
    <Limit DELE>
      DenyAll
    </Limit>
    <Limit RMD>
      DenyAll
    </Limit>
  </Directory>
```

If there is any better bullet proof way to disable deleting and also some examples on how I can prevent editing/writing as well.

Edit:

Just to note, I can't simply do with permissions because I use the owner and group to calculate quotas in an advanced way. Also, editing and deleting is allowed through the panel, which gets ran as their user. However, I don't want them to be able to do it VIA FTP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use a configuration like this:

```
<Directory ~/site/backups>
   <Limit WRITE>
      DenyAll
   </Limit>
</Directory>
```

which essentially does the same as this configuration:

```
<Directory ~/site/backups>
   # Delete Files
   <Limit DELE>
     DenyAll
   </Limit>

   # Remove directories
   <Limit RMD>
     DenyAll
   </Limit>

   # Make Directory
   <Limit MKD>
     DenyAll
   </Limit>

   # Rename From / To
   <Limit RNFR>
     DenyAll
   </Limit>
   <Limit RNTO>
     DenyAll
   </Limit>

   # Write Files
   <Limit STOR>
     DenyAll
   </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, not only did it solve my problem with my backup dir but other directories I wanted everything disabled but STOR. Thanks

Comment: You have two blocks for Delete Files